# Arduino Uno- Analog serial monitor not reading values over 174

Tags: arduino-uno, programming

I am simultaneously using a LEGO sound sensor in pin A5 and a RadioShack Tricolor LED Strip (Product #2760339) in pin A0.

The sound sensor alone works as expected (producing values based on volume) running only code to read the value and output to the serial monitor. However when I upload the program to use the LED strip, read the sensor value and output to the serial monitor, the sensor value caps at 174.

The program given to run the LED strip can be found at http://blog.radioshack.com/2013/06/tricolor-led-strip/
The code I added to this was pulled mostly directly from the AnalogInOutSerial example provided by Arduino.

Here is the full code;

```
/***************************************************************************/    
//            Hardware: RadioShack Tricolor LED Strip
//            Arduino IDE: Arduino-1.0
//            Date:      April 17, 2013
//            Copyright© 2013 RadioShack Corporation
//
//  This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
//  modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
//  License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
//  version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
//
//  This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
//  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
//  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
//  Lesser General Public License for more details.
//
//  You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
//  License along with this library; if not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>
//
/*****************************************************************************/

#include <avr/pgmspace.h>

// ******** DEBUG ==== should auto config to adapt different mother board *********
//#define DATA_1 (PORTF |=  0X01)    // DATA 1    // for ATMEGA
//#define DATA_0 (PORTF &=  0XFE)    // DATA 0    // for ATMEGA
//#define STRIP_PINOUT DDRF=0xFF  // for ATMEGA
#define DATA_1 (PORTC |=  0X01)    // DATA 1    // for UNO
#define DATA_0 (PORTC &=  0XFE)    // DATA 0    // for UNO
#define STRIP_PINOUT (DDRC=0xFF)    // for UNO

PROGMEM const unsigned long rainbow_full[5][10]={
  {0xff0000,0x00ff00,0x0000ff,0xffff00,0xff00ff,0xffffff,0xff6622,0xff0000,0xff0000,0xff0000},

};
PROGMEM const unsigned long off[1][10] = {
   {0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
};
PROGMEM const unsigned long red1[1][10] = {
   {0xff0000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
};
PROGMEM const unsigned long red2[1][10] = {
   {0xff0000,0xff0000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
};
PROGMEM const unsigned long red3[1][10] = {
   {0xff0000,0xff0000,0xff0000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
};
PROGMEM const unsigned long red4[1][10] = {
   {0xff0000,0xff0000,0xff0000,0xff0000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
};
PROGMEM const unsigned long red5[1][10] = {
   {0xff0000,0xff0000,0xff0000,0xff0000,0xff0000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
};
PROGMEM const unsigned long red6[1][10] = {
   {0xff0000,0xff0000,0xff0000,0xff0000,0xff0000,0xff0000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
};
PROGMEM const unsigned long red7[1][10] = {
   {0xff0000,0xff0000,0xff0000,0xff0000,0xff0000,0xff0000,0xff0000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
};
PROGMEM const unsigned long red8[1][10] = {
   {0xff0000,0xff0000,0xff0000,0xff0000,0xff0000,0xff0000,0xff0000,0xff0000,0x000000,0x000000},
};
PROGMEM const unsigned long red9[1][10] = {
   {0xff0000,0xff0000,0xff0000,0xff0000,0xff0000,0xff0000,0xff0000,0xff0000,0xff0000,0x000000},
};
PROGMEM const unsigned long redfull[1][10] = {
   {0xff0000,0xff0000,0xff0000,0xff0000,0xff0000,0xff0000,0xff0000,0xff0000,0xff0000,0xff0000},
};


/*PROGMEM const unsigned long pattern_test_blue[10][10]={
  {0x00ff00,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x00ff00,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x000000,0x00ff00,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x00ff00,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x00ff00,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x00ff00,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x00ff00,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x00ff00,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x00ff00,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x00ff00},
};

PROGMEM const unsigned long pattern_test_green[10][10]={
  {0x0000ff,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x0000ff,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x000000,0x0000ff,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x0000ff,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x0000ff,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x0000ff,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x0000ff,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x0000ff,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x0000ff,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x0000ff},
};

PROGMEM const unsigned long pattern_test_white[10][10]={
  {0xffffff,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0xffffff,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x000000,0xffffff,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0xffffff,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0xffffff,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0xffffff,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0xffffff,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0xffffff,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0xffffff,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0xffffff},
};

PROGMEM const unsigned long pattern_test_comet1[][10]={
  {0xffffff,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x444444,0xffffff,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x111111,0x444444,0xffffff,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x111111,0x444444,0xffffff,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x000000,0x111111,0x444444,0xffffff,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x111111,0x444444,0xffffff,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x111111,0x444444,0xffffff,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x111111,0x444444,0xffffff,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x111111,0x444444,0xffffff,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x111111,0x444444,0xffffff},
};

PROGMEM const unsigned long pattern_test_comet2[][10]={
  {0xffffff,0x000000,0x000000,0x111111,0x444444,0xffffff,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x444444,0xffffff,0x000000,0x000000,0x111111,0x444444,0xffffff,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x111111,0x444444,0xffffff,0x000000,0x000000,0x111111,0x444444,0xffffff,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x111111,0x444444,0xffffff,0x000000,0x000000,0x111111,0x444444,0xffffff,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x000000,0x111111,0x444444,0xffffff,0x000000,0x000000,0x111111,0x444444,0xffffff},
  {0xffffff,0x000000,0x000000,0x111111,0x444444,0xffffff,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x444444,0xffffff,0x000000,0x000000,0x111111,0x444444,0xffffff,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x111111,0x444444,0xffffff,0x000000,0x000000,0x111111,0x444444,0xffffff,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x111111,0x444444,0xffffff,0x000000,0x000000,0x111111,0x444444,0xffffff,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x000000,0x111111,0x444444,0xffffff,0x000000,0x000000,0x111111,0x444444,0xffffff},
};

PROGMEM const unsigned long pattern_test_comet3[][10]={
  {0xffffff,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0xffffff},
  {0x444444,0xffffff,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0xffffff,0x444444},
  {0x111111,0x444444,0xffffff,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0xffffff,0x444444,0x111111},
  {0x000000,0x111111,0x444444,0xffffff,0x000000,0x000000,0xffffff,0x444444,0x111111,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x000000,0x111111,0x444444,0xffffff,0xffffff,0x444444,0x111111,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x000000,0x111111,0x444444,0xffffff,0xffffff,0x444444,0x111111,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0xffffff,0x444444,0x444444,0xffffff,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x000000,0xffffff,0x444444,0x111111,0x111111,0x444444,0xffffff,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0xffffff,0x444444,0x111111,0x000000,0x000000,0x111111,0x444444,0xffffff,0x000000},
  {0xffffff,0x444444,0x111111,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0x111111,0x444444,0xffffff},
};

PROGMEM const unsigned long pattern_test_rainbow[10][10]={
  {0xff0000,0xff7f00,0xffff00,0x00ff00,0x0000ff,0x6f00ff,0x8f00ff,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0xff0000,0xff7f00,0xffff00,0x00ff00,0x0000ff,0x6f00ff,0x8f00ff,0x000000,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x000000,0xff0000,0xff7f00,0xffff00,0x00ff00,0x0000ff,0x6f00ff,0x8f00ff,0x000000},
  {0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0xff0000,0xff7f00,0xffff00,0x00ff00,0x0000ff,0x6f00ff,0x8f00ff},
  {0x8f00ff,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0xff0000,0xff7f00,0xffff00,0x00ff00,0x0000ff,0x6f00ff},
  {0x6f00ff,0x8f00ff,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0xff0000,0xff7f00,0xffff00,0x00ff00,0x0000ff},
  {0x0000ff,0x6f00ff,0x8f00ff,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0xff0000,0xff7f00,0xffff00,0x00ff00},
  {0x00ff00,0x0000ff,0x6f00ff,0x8f00ff,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0xff0000,0xff7f00,0xffff00},
  {0xffff00,0x00ff00,0x0000ff,0x6f00ff,0x8f00ff,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0xff0000,0xff7f00},
  {0xff7f00,0xffff00,0x00ff00,0x0000ff,0x6f00ff,0x8f00ff,0x000000,0x000000,0x000000,0xff0000},
};


*/

// ***********************************************************************************************************
// *
// *                            Power Up Init.
// *
// *
// ***********************************************************************************************************

int sensorvalue = 0;
int outputvalue = 0;
void setup() {




  STRIP_PINOUT;        // set output pin - DEBUG: should auto detect which mother board for use


  reset_strip();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //noInterrupts();

}



// ***********************************************************************************************************
// *
// *                            Main Loop 
// *
// *
// ***********************************************************************************************************
void loop() 
{




    sensorvalue = analogRead(A5);
    outputvalue = map(sensorvalue, 0, 174, 0, 18);
    if(outputvalue == 0){
      send_1M_pattern(off, 1, 20);
    }

    else if(outputvalue > 0 && outputvalue <= 3){
      send_1M_pattern(red1, 1, 20);
    }
    else if(outputvalue > 3 && outputvalue <= 5){
      send_1M_pattern(red2, 1, 20);
    }
    else if(outputvalue > 5 && outputvalue <= 7){
      send_1M_pattern(red3, 1, 20);
    }
    else if(outputvalue > 7 && outputvalue <= 9){
      send_1M_pattern(red4, 1, 20);
    }

    else if(outputvalue > 9 && outputvalue <= 11){
      send_1M_pattern(red5, 1, 20);
    }

    else if(outputvalue > 11 && outputvalue <= 13){
      send_1M_pattern(red6, 1, 20);
    }

    else if(outputvalue > 13 && outputvalue <= 16){
      send_1M_pattern(red9, 1, 20);
    }

    else if(outputvalue > 16){
      send_1M_pattern(rainbow_full, 1, 20);
    }
    Serial.print("sensor = " );
    Serial.print(sensorvalue);
    Serial.print("\t output = ");
    Serial.println(outputvalue);

    delay(2);







  /*
    frame++;
    if(frame<=10) LEDSTRIP_PATTERN_0();
    if(10<frame<=20) LEDSTRIP_PATTERN_0();
    if(20<frame<=30) LEDSTRIP_PATTERN_0();
    if(frame>30) frame=1;
   */
  //delay(1);
}


/*******************************************************************************
 * Function Name  : send_1M_pattern
 * Description    : Transmit pattern to whole 1 meter strip
 *                  
 * Input          : pointer to ROM pattern; pattern length; frame rate
 *                  
 * Output         : None
 * Return         : None
 *******************************************************************************/
void send_1M_pattern(const unsigned long data[][10], int pattern_no, int frame_rate)
{
  int i=0;
  int j=0;
  uint32_t temp_data;

  for (i=0;i<pattern_no;i++)
  {
    noInterrupts();
    for (j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
      temp_data=pgm_read_dword_near(&data[i][j]);
      send_strip(temp_data);
    }
    interrupts();

    delay(frame_rate);

  }




}


/*******************************************************************************
 * Function Name  : send_strip
 * Description    : Transmit 24 pulse to LED strip
 *                  
 * Input          : 24-bit data for the strip
 *                  
 * Output         : None
 * Return         : None
 *******************************************************************************/
void send_strip(uint32_t data)
{
  int i;
  unsigned long j=0x800000;


  for (i=0;i<24;i++)
  {
    if (data & j)
    {
      DATA_1;
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");    
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");

/*----------------------------*/
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");  
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");  
      __asm__("nop\n\t");  
      __asm__("nop\n\t");        
/*----------------------------*/      
      DATA_0;
    }
    else
    {
      DATA_1;
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");    
      DATA_0;
/*----------------------------*/      
       __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");
      __asm__("nop\n\t");      
/*----------------------------*/         
    }

    j>>=1;
  }



}

/*******************************************************************************
 * Function Name  : reset_strip
 * Description    : Send reset pulse to reset all color of the strip
 *                  
 * Input          : None
 *                  
 * Output         : None
 * Return         : None
 *******************************************************************************/
void    reset_strip()
{
  DATA_0;
  delayMicroseconds(20);
}
```

Comment: Please include your code here. While one may say "code came from such-and-such", it is possible that interactions between various pieces of code can cause complications.

Comment: I have included the code.

Comment: So you're saying that just performing the `analogRead()` on the audio sensor alone without the rest of the code gives results from 0 to 1023? Is this regardless of whether or not the other electronics is in place?

Comment: Correct, I have discovered that the sensor reading is independent on the other electronics plugged in, yet is is dependent on the statement `STRIP_PINOUT;` in the setup function. If that statement is excluded from the code, the sensor reads normally, but the LED strip does not work.

Comment: To be clear, when I say the sensor reads normally, I am getting values around 0 with no sound, and no more than 500 with music playing as loud as my ears can handle, with no visible cap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A5 is PC5. Your code sets it as an output. Since you only need A0 (PC0) to be an output:

```
#define STRIP_PINOUT (DDRC = _BV(PC0))
```

[Uno pin mappings](http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/PinMapping168)

Comment: I can see *why* this example code skips the usual Arduino I/O abstraction for its direct assembly bit-banging, but it is unfortunate as it makes their code hard to combine with anything else written in terms of Arduino pin names.

Comment: I am particularly amused by the repeated `__asm__("nop\n\t");` lines. I suppose they didn't know about `_delay_us()` et alia.

Comment: This probably gives them finer control, particularly for very short intervals.  Likely the code was tuned for maximum performance shifting data to the strip, with a scope against the data sheet, or possibly by reducing to the point of failure and then backing off.

Comment: It also locks it to a single CPU clock speed, versus using the adaptive delay macros found in AVR Libc.